# Mudar um option de um select de acordo com a escolha de outro select (Formulario HTML)

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Olá, é o seguinte.

Tenho uma área de um formulário na qual eu seleciona o código da empresa, empresa e também mostro a tributação daquela empresa.

Vou mostrar a imagem dos campos: (o meu problema é na parte marcada em vermelho)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O COD e Empresa são listados dinamicamente via PHP e AJAX com uma consulta no banco de dados que lista as empresas que são de responsabilidade do usuário logado. E a Tributação é mostrada de acordo com a Tributação da empresa (Cada empresa pode ter 5 tipos de Tributação).

Eu gostaria do seguinte, quando eu mudasse o COD, a Empresa correspondente a aquele Código e sua Tributação fossem mudados no select automaticamente.

E gostaria também que fosse feito o mesmo quando eu mudasse a Empresa. O COD e a Tributação também fossem mudados.

Lembrando que esses dados todos estão atrelados a uma mesma tabela MySQL. E todos eles estão uns ligados aos outros.

Eu consegui fazer uma "Gambi" em que quase resolvo essa situação. Quando mudo o COD, a empresa e a Tributação correspondentes também são alterados. Porém, não acontece o mesmo quando altero a empresa. A única coisa que muda é a tributação.

OBS: COD e Empresas são `<select>` e Tributação é um `<input type="text">`.

Vou deixar aqui o meu código (Com a "Gambi") para ver se vocês conseguem me ajudar.

```js
//FUNCAO PARA PRENCHER SELECT EMPRESA E TRIBUTAÇÃO DE ACORDO COM O CÓDIGO (COD) ESCOLHIDO

$(function() {
  $("select#codigo-empresa").change(function(e) {
    var cod = $("select#codigo-empresa option:selected").attr('id');
    $("select#nome-empresa").val(cod);

    var trib = $("select#codigo-empresa option:selected").attr('name');
    $("input[id='tributacao']").val(trib);

  });
});


//FUNCAO PARA PRENCHER SELECT COD E TRIBUTAÇÃO DE ACORDO COM A EMPRESA ESCOLHIDA

$(function() {
  $("select#nome-empresa").change(function(e) {
    var codigo = $("select#nome-empresa option:selected").attr('id');
    
    $("select#codigo-empresa").val(codigo);
    
    var tribu = $("select#nome-empresa option:selected").attr('name');
    $("input[id='tributacao']").val(tribu);

  });
});
```

```html
<!-- LINHA -->
<div class="col-lg-12 alinhar-texto-no-centro" id="selecionar-empresas">
  <h3 class="alinhar-texto-no-centro">Selecionar Empresa</h3>

  <!-- CAMPO CODIGO DA EMPRESA -->
  <div class="form-group col-lg-2">
    <label for="codigo-empresa">COD</label>
    <select name="codigo-empresa" id="codigo-empresa" class="input form-control">
      <?php
        while($registros_cod = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_pegar_cod)){
      ?>
        <option id="<?php echo $registros_cod['EMPRESAS'];?>" name="<?php echo $registros_cod[" TRIBUTACAO "];?>">
          <?php echo  $registros_cod['COD']; ?>
        </option>
        <?php
        }
    ?>
    </select>
  </div>
  <!-- CAMPO EMPRESA -->
  <div class="form-group col-lg-7">
    <label for="nome-empresa">Empresa</label>
    <select name="nome-empresa" id="nome-empresa" class="input form-control">
      <?php
      while($registros_empresas =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_pegar_empresa))
        {
      ?>
        <option id="<?php echo utf8_encode($registros_empresas['EMPRESAS']);?> " name="<?php echo utf8_encode($registros_empresas[" TRIBUTACAO "]); ?> ">
      <?php echo utf8_encode($registros_empresas['EMPRESAS']); ?>
        </option>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </select>
  </div>
  <!-- CAMPO TRIBUTAÇÃO -->
  <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
    <label for="tributacao">Tributação</label>
    <input name="tributacao" id="tributacao" class="input form-control" readonly></input>
  </div>
  <!-- CAMPO POSSUIR ARQUIVOS -->
  <div class="form-group col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-9" id="lista-empresas" style="display:inline">
    <label for="nome-empresa">Listar Empresas</label>
    <select name="empresas-filtro" id="empresas-filtro" class="input form-control">
      <option>Minhas</option>
      <option>Todas</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- LINHA -->
```

Desde já, agradeço. Obrigado!

Comment: Como vc está fazendo pra buscar os dados no banco ao mudar o option?

Comment: Eu não estou pegando os dados no banco. Eu atribui valores aos ID e NAME dos option. Então quando eu mudo o option de um select, então eu adiciono o ID desse campo ao option do outro select. Lembrando que os values e os ID, dos dois selects, são resultantes de uma consulta no banco de dados. Por exemplo, como id do opstion COD eu coloco o nome da empresa correspondente a esse código. E como id do option Empresas, eu coloco o COD correspondente ao nome dessa empresa. Não sei se consegui ser claro ...

Comment: Se houver um modo mais fácil pra fazer essa ação, eu aceito.

Comment: Provavelmente a resposta é muito simples, mas eu achei complicado entender o que você quer fazer. Os dados que você quer que sejam exibidos ou não, não estão vindo do banco correto? será que criar arrays com options não resolveriam seu problema? Ou seja, quando escolhesse uma option o outro select seria populado com a array A se escolhesse outra option o outro select seria populado com a array B.

Comment: Vinícius, cada select daquele tem uns 50 itens. Um select listando as empresas e outro select listando o código da empresa. Vou tentar ser o mais claro possível agora. Gostaria de que quando eu selecionasse a empresa "A" no primeiro select, fosse selecionado automaticamente o código "1" no segundo select. E quando eu selecionasse o código "10" no segundo select, fosse selecionado automaticamente a empresa "J" no primeiro select. E assim sucessivamente.(Lembrando que A é a 1ª letra do alfabeto e a letra J é a 10ª). Tentei ser o mais claro possível agora. Os dados nos options são vindo do banco.